# Parse and deserialize JSON object in android

Tags: android, json

I am working on an android application. I have the following data in `JSON` and the data will be changed every time,so I don't know what are the key values. I need to parse it and deserialize in order to save it in `SQL Lite`.

```
{
    "genre":"2",
    "imported_from":"1",
    "release_year":"1999",
    "import":"1",
    "label":"1",
    "artist":"Boards Of Canada ", 
    "album_title":"Music Has The Right To Children",
    "formats":"1"
}
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
String inputJSONString = ""; // Your string JSON here
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(inputJSONString);
Iterator<String> keys = jObject.keys();

while( keys.hasNext() ) {
   String key = keys.next();
   String value = jObject.getString(key);
}
```